# How to lock a PDF File after a few days

Tags: pdf, passwords, acrobat, days

is there a way to lock a PDF file after a given number of days? like for example i am making a document in ms word and i export it into a PDF file with a password that locks the PDF file after 3 days... So the user can open that PDF file and read the content but after 3 days he/she cannot open it anymore unless he/she knows the password.

Comment: How "hard" should that protection be? …and parallel to that, how much ($$) is that protection worth to you?

Comment: the content of that PDF is confidential so i need to lock it after the given time expires.

Comment: You might have a look at solutions by FileOpen, or another DRM (Digital Rights Management) system. A "soft" solution using Acrobat JavaScript is in this case not really applicable.